# Prevent WordPress plugin activation on wrong versions of PHP or WP

Tags: plugins, wordpress, activation

Is there a way to prevent WordPress from activating a plugin, when I click *"Activate"*, and PHP or WP have the wrong versions?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
   register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'bh_proljece_boj_install' );
   function bh_proljece_boj_install() 
   {
       if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '3.3', ' < ' ) ) 
       {
           deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) ); // Deactivate our plugin
       }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: While not technically preventing the activation to happen, this is the less bad answer.

Comment: FYI: This feature is being developed in the WordPress core [reference](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43992).

Answer (score -1):

There is a global variable `$wp_version` or you could use `get_bloginfo('version')` to get the WordPress version. You could also use the `version_compare(...)` PHP function for PHP version comparison where both verifications could be evaluated in your plugin activation function.

Comment: No no, that's not what I`m asking. I know how to verify that, but I want to know if there's a way to prevent WordPress from activating the plugin.

Comment: WP plugins have activation hooks - see [register_activation_hook function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) and you can use the function to decide if a plugin is activatable or not.

Comment: An how exactly do I decide if a plugin is activable or not?